# Python program hangs, can't figure out why

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to run this fairly simple program that tells you how many months it'll take to afford a down-payment on a house given the annual salary of the person, the percent of their salary to save, and the total cost of the house, here's the code:

```
annual_salary = float(input("Enter your annual salary: "))
portion_saved = float(input("Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal: "))
total_cost = float(input("Enter the cost of your dream home: "))

portion_down_payment = total_cost * 0.25
current_savings = 0.0
monthly_salary = annual_salary / 12
percentage_of_monthly = monthly_salary * portion_saved

months = 0
while current_savings != portion_down_payment:
    current_savings += percentage_of_monthly
    investment_return = current_savings*0.04 / 12
    current_savings += investment_return
    months += 1

print("Number of months:", months)
```

I've done Python programming before and I am fairly familiar with Java, but I'm a wee bit rusty with Python so I can't figure out why this is happening, here's the output:

[code output when ran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TDyY.png)

As you can see, the code doesn't do anything after inputting the total cost of the "dream house", however, it does not provide an error message either. And being the stubborn person I am, I guessed it might've been the IDE, which it wasn't as I tried the same program on Spyder and in the Command Prompt, and still had no luck

Comment: It isn't very clear what logic you're trying to achieve, but think about whether you want to continue the loop when `current_savings > portion_down_payment`.

Comment: I'd use some printing for debugging, for example `print(current_savings, portion_down_payment)` in every loop and check, what is going wrong. But basically the `portion_down_payment` is not going to be `==` to `current_savings` and your loop is going forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your while statement is stuck in a loop-

```
while current_savings != portion_down_payment:
```

You're doing a direct match there- if it is less than or greater than it will continue, the loop only stops if the current_savings is exactly equal to the portion_down_payment. The odds of this happening are very very slim, especially when dealing with floating point numbers.

Setting it to `while current_savings < portion_down_payment` should solve  your problem.

Comment: Following the submission of this post, the day after, or the day after that, I realized that it would continue to loop forever because current_savings would never equal portion_down_payment. So I tried what you recommended and it worked. Thanks for the help!